# Select all but the latest row

Tags: mysql

I have a table to store the login history of clients. One of the captured fields is the timestamp. I am trying to write a query to get all but the last row in the login history for a user.

I thought something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM LoginHistory L 
WHERE USER_ID like 'testuser@company.com' 
HAVING L.TIMESTAMP < MAX(L.TIMESTAMP);
```

This seems to select only the first row. Any idea why this is happening and how to do it correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM LoginHistory L 
WHERE USER_ID = 'testuser@company.com' 
AND L.TIMESTAMP < (SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) FROM LoginHistory WHERE USER_ID = 'testuser@company.com');
```

Comment: Thanks. Although is there a reason mysql can't / won't do this with just one select?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is NOT EQUALS to MAX -

```
SELECT * FROM LoginHistory L 
WHERE USER_ID like 'testuser@company.com'
AND L.TIMESTAMP <> ( 
    select MAX(L.TIMESTAMP) fromLoginHistory 
    where USER_ID like 'testuser@company.com'
)
```

Comment: When you just group by user_id you will only get 1 record, it's one of MySQLs quirks...

Comment: Weird. I've never seen group by behave this was before. Is this documented anywhere? Thanks

Comment: @Chris - GroupBy will return one record since your where condition has user_id like '' condition. Anyway, have edited my query to remove groupby.